# InnoSetup, change the Uninstallable property behavior at runtime?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

> SCENARIO

I have created an installer that will installs a Malware application for educative purposes, the installer contains these two tasks:

```
[Tasks]
Name: hidden; Description: Hidden mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode
Name: visible; Description: Visible mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode
```

This means, performs a hidden installation for the user (hidden dirs and files and make uninstallabe the installer), or a visible installation (normal dirs and files and Uninstallable=True).

> PROBLEM

I've set the `Uninstallable=True` by default, but If the user selects the `hidden` task then I would like to avoid the uninstaller creation.

How I could do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code shown in the [`Uninstallable`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable) directive documentation:

```
[Setup]
...
Uninstallable=not IsTaskSelected('hidden')

[Tasks]
Name: hidden; Description: Hidden mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode
Name: visible; Description: Visible mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode
```

Optionally, if you'd need more complex statements written in reusable function, or access some of the scripting code elements, you could write a function, e.g.:

```
[Setup]
...
Uninstallable=IsUninstallable

[Tasks]
Name: hidden; Description: Hidden mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode
Name: visible; Description: Visible mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode

[Code]
function IsUninstallable: Boolean;
begin
  Result := WizardSilent or not IsTaskSelected('hidden');
end;
```