# Avoid empty directory when installing no components with inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup

We have two products, **A** and **B**.

**B** can be a standalone application and has its own installer created with Inno Setup.

**A**'s installer is also built with Inno Setup and will include the **B** installer as one of the [files].

When you are installing **A** you have a number of options, one of which is to install **B**. It is possible for the user to be distributed the **A** installer but decide to **only** install **B** from the list of options.

When the user picks **B** from the component list the **B** installer is run in the [run] section.

We've noticed that if the user only chooses **B** from **A**'s installer then we still get **A** listed as an installed application in the Windows program list. Also, an almost empty folder is added to Program Files. The application's folder contains only an uninstaller and the icon for the uninstaller. Running the uninstaller removes these files.

Is there some way to avoid creating this directory and adding **A** to the program list if the user only wants to install **B**?

Comment: I believe you are looking for a way to tell the A installer to be *not uninstallable* at runtime according to certain condition(s). If so, then you might get inspiration in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27981658/960757), where you can replace `IsTaskSelected` with `IsComponentSelected` or any statement (combination) that will evaluate to a boolean result.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Using the info from that post I was able to get rid of the uninstaller, however, it's still making an empty folder for **A**. I'll poke around some more to see if I can figure out why. It's possible I could simply delete the folder if we don't need it and it's empty.